# file_get_contents with Proxy

Tags: php, proxy, file-get-contents

I am having some trouble with using Proxy route with `file_get_contents`. When i use it with `cURL` it works, but not with this code:

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/xml');
$url = "http://google.com/";
$proxy = 'http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443';
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        'proxy' => $proxy,
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => implode("\r\n", $headers),
        'timeout' => 500,
        "content" => $request,
    ],
];
$stream_context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $stream_context);
return $data;
```

Problem is that this **does not hit my proxy server first**, but goes direct to google.com.

when i use this code with cURL it **works perfect:**

```
$handle = curl_init();
$url = "http://google.com";
$proxy = 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443';
// Set the url
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
echo $output;
```

Could anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: All the examples I can find for `proxy` use the `tcp` scheme rather than `http`, even for HTTP proxies.

Comment: i tried both with `tcp` and `http`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong Protocol

try using:

```
$proxy = 'tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443';
```

also try adding the following to your $opts array:

```
'request_fulluri'=>true
```

Comment: I tried using `$proxy = 'tcp://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443' and added  'request_fulluri=>true' in opts  but still not going trough my Proxy

Comment: Any one that have a solution?